# Parsing a nested JSON using Decodable

Tags: json, swift, decodable

My JSON structure looks like this:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "Ok",
    "etag": "7232324423",
    "data": {
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 25,
        "results": [{
                "id": 1011244,
                "name": "Miss Nesbit",
                "description": "",
                "modified": "2018-04-04T20:15:35-0400",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "path": "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/i/mg/8/70/4c002efc322e3",
                    "extension": "jpg"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 1011244,
                "name": "Miss Solis",
                "description": "",
                "modified": "2018-09-04T20:15:35-0400",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "path": "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/i/mg/8/70/4c002efc382e3",
                    "extension": "jpg"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to parse the results in a struct as follows:

```
struct Character: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let thumbnail: Thumbnail
    let description: String
}
```

However I'm a bit confused about where I specify I only want the `results` part ? Would I do it when implementing Decodable as follows?

```
let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
let data = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .data)
let results = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .results)
```

Or do we have to map out each nested section? ANy help or guidance would be so appreciated! :)

Comment: Character is a native Swift type. You should choose an alternative name for your struct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapping out the *relevant* keys is necessary to drill down for you, yes.

You can use `app.quicktype.io` to get started fast and remove the non-relevant keys if you really don‘t want to parse the rest or leave it there if you may want to use it later.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So in this case, would : `code, status, etag, data` be relevant and then i can drill down within data to get the results? I thought I'd be able to ignore the outer part but I guess i'm wrong!

Comment: @vanilla_splsh Only `let data: DataStruct` is relevant from the first level, so you and Swift know there is a data-field you can drill into. This DataStruct then has a `let results: [CharacterStruct]` field, so you can access the array encoded in JSON as an `Array` inside Swift. [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/382-encoding-decoding-and-serialization-in-swift-4) is a tutorial on the `Codable`-API. You can ignore everything except where he embeds one struct into another and an array into a struct/class. If you want to do this manually you can use differing CodingKey enums per level & class.

Comment: Thank you for your help, makes complete sense now and I got it working!

Answer (score 2):

You can use my extension helper [NestedDecodable](https://github.com/aunnnn/NestedDecodable), which allows you to extract `Decodable` from a `keyPath`. It adds this method to `JSONDecoder`:

```swift
decoder.decode(Class, from: Data, keyPath: String)
```

A key path specifies the nested path to the model you want, separated by `.`

So using your example, this works (tested):

```swift
let characters = try decoder.decode([Character].self, from: data, keyPath: "data.results")
```

---

Internally, it creates a wrapper struct to hold your target `Decodable` class, split `keyPath` by `.`, then for-loop each key down until it reaches the final keyed decoding container, decode that model and returns. [Ref](https://github.com/aunnnn/NestedDecodable/blob/master/NestedDecodable.swift)